# Python gives "int is not iterable" error even though the code looks clean

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm basically trying to code the algorithm of counting inversions (with the divide & conquer strategy of merge sort). I first tried to test it in a small array, but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cntinv.py", line 26, in <module>
    ans = count_inversions(array)[1]
  File "cntinv.py", line 19, in count_inversions
    a, left = count_inversions(array[:mid])
  File "cntinv.py", line 19, in count_inversions
    a, left = count_inversions(array[:mid])
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Here's my code:

```
def count_split_inversions(a, b):
    c, cnt = [], 0
    while len(a) > 0 and len(b) > 0:
        if b[0] < a[0]:
            c.append(b.pop(0))
            cnt += len(a)
        else:
            c.append(a.pop(0))
    if len(a) > 0:
        c.extend(a)
    else:
        c.extend(b)
    return(c, cnt)

def count_inversions(array):
    n = len(array)

    if n <= 1: return(0)

    mid = n // 2
    a, left = count_inversions(array[:mid])
    b, right = count_inversions(array[mid:])
    c, split = count_split_inversions(a, b)

    return(c, left + right + split)

array = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6]
ans = count_inversions(array)[1]
print("The answer is:", str(ans))
```

I couldn't find the mistake with the help of the error message. So I'd be grateful if you help me point my mistake.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: That's it. Found the error! :) Thanks. I can't believe I didn't see that. :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `n <= 0`, `count_inversions()` returns `0`, instead of a tuple:

```
def count_inversions(array):
    ...
    if n <= 1: return(0)
    ...
```

Since the calling function expects a tuple, this results in an error.